# Puppet copy Issue

Tags: copy, puppet

I am very new to puppet and I configured a puppetmaster and an agent.

Here I am trying to simply copy and paste the file from my local centos7 (master server) to an agent on a specific path and replace an existing file with the new one.

This is how I try to do this:

```
file { '/tmp/test.txt':
      ensure => present,
      source => "/tmp/test.txt",
}
```

However - I am getting error seen below:

```
Could not evaluate:
   Could not retrieve information from environment production source(s) file:/tmp/test.txt
```

I have gone through a number of links but don't know where is the exact issue.
Any suggestion on this ??

Comment: You're misunderstanding Puppet. It's not a tool that copies files around. You'll need to spend a bit of time learning Puppet first I think.

Comment: Did the number of links you went through include [the actual Puppet documentation](https://puppet.com/docs)?  That's always a good place to start.  In particular, you could consider reading [the docs for the File resource type](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/types/file.html).

Comment: Thanks I think you are right first i need to learn about this. I am actually trying to manage Apache server in my environment and that apache is too customised and complied. I thought i can make a copy of a httpd.conf file and place it on server and make changes as per requirement and push that same on relevant server so is it possible ??